# Is there any ancient story in which individuals are born in the opposite sex in the rebirth?

Tags: puranas, rebirth

Hindus believe in rebirth. We have several ancient stories on that. In many of our stories, if a male or a female dies, he or she takes rebirth in the same sex.

Is there any story in our mythology in which individuals are born in the opposite sex in their rebirth?

Comment: Yes. There are many such stories in Puranas.

Comment: Amba was reborn as Shikandin, though the circumstances were special.

Comment: user1952500, Shikandin is neither man or woman, is Ali (3rd gender )

Comment: @Kuhan, that is one of the special circumstances mentioned. And Shikhandin was not born as the same gender as the previous birth which is what the question asked.

Comment: if you think of women all the time you will be reborn as a woman....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Is there any story, about born on opposite sex?**

Yes, there is a story of King **Puranjana** in Shreemad Bhagvat purana, where the King Puranjana was reborn as women-  [**SB 4.28**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/28) : Purañjana Becomes a woman in the next Life.

This is an ancient story told by Narada to king Prachinbarhi.

> **Background** - This is a story of King Puranjana who was engaged in sense gratification throughout his life. Unkind king, Purañjana, had killed many animals in various sacrifices. Now, taking advantage of this opportunity, all these animals began to pierce him with their horns.  Due to his contaminated association with women King Purañjana suffered very much and lost his kingdom.And at the end he died remembering his wife , so he was reborn as a women.

Now it is believed that whatever a man constantly thinks in his death bed or while dying, he gets rebirth according to his last thoughts.

So king Puranjana died thinking of his wife and reborn as a woman.

> तामेव मनसा गृह्यन बभूव प्रमदोत्तमा ।
>  
>     अनन्तरं विदर्भस्य राजसिंहस्य वेश्मनि ।।28।।
>
> tām eva manasā gṛhṇan babhūva pramadottamā
>  
>     anantaraṁ vidarbhasya rāja-siṁhasya veśmani
>
> **King Purañjana gave up his body while remembering his wife, and consequently in his next life he became a very beautiful and
>   well-situated woman**. He took his next birth as the daughter of King
>   Vidarbha in the very house of the King.[**SB 4.28.28**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/28/28)

Comment: Great answer, specially this line "So king Puranjana died thinking of his wife and reborn as women.". I also heard a story like this in which a king (don't remember name) who use to take care of a deer. On his death time he was keep worrying about that deer so he got his next birth as a deer. It is said that at your death time you have to make your focus only on parbrahma, if you won't do that even in your last moment then you will be punished, and as a punishment you will get same thing that will be in your mind the most.

Comment: @Rishabh - Thanks.Yes there is another similar story of King Bharata in SB ,where he was reborned as a deer in extreme affection towatds him. And dying while thinking about dear reborned as deer in next birth -https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/8/27